# Событие при наведении на ссылку

Tags: jquery, javascript

Уважаемые, замучился маниторить интернет в поисках нужного мануала или функции. Решил написать. Подскажите, как реализовать простую функцию на jQuery. Есть ссылка с классом `link` и есть див с классом `linc2`. А теперь сама функция: при наведении на ссылку должен появиться див с классом `linc2`, после чего на него можно было навести курсор и что-нибудь нажать, но после того, как курсор с него уходит или уходит чтобы он опять пропадал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="place" style="width:300px; height:200px;">
 <div class="link" style="width:300px; height:100px;">Link</div>
 <div class="linc2" style="width:300px; height:100px;background-color:green;display:none">Tooltip</div>
</div>
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('#place').hover(function(){
    $('.linc2').show();
   },
   function(){
    $('.linc2').hide();
   });
 });
</script>
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/zQgWw/)

Comment: нефиговая имитация

Comment: В смысле, @Spectre ?

Comment: а что непонятного? если `hover` висит не на ссылке, а нa родительском элементе ссылки и блока

Comment: а что тут, простите, «нефигового»? На любой DOM-элемент же можно повесить событие.  
Если честно, просто первое, что пришло в голову. Про `.mouseleave()` даже как-то не подумал.

Comment: по-моему это у всех верстальщиков так - сделать костыли с помощью фиксированых размеров элементов, я не говорю, что решение плохое, просто оно мне не нравится

Comment: А, ну да, согласен, с точки зрения эстетики — это не лучший пример.

Comment: Realetive__ прав. Если hover поставить на ссылку, то при переходе курсора на блок, последний будет пропадать. А так все будет впорядке.

Comment: я позволил себе немного исправить решение @oneboy - [http://jsfiddle.net/V6VWC/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/V6VWC/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [сюда](http://jsfiddle.net/oneboy/V6VWC/1/)